# 'canvas.mpl_connect' doestn't work inside a class

Tags: python, matplotlib, canvas

I am trying to make a response (return the value of `event.xdata`) concerning the mouse press event on `fig`. But it doesn't work. Could anyone tell me if there is anything wrong with my code? Thank you guys.

```
class ImDisp(mywindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super(ImDisp,self).__init__()

    def BsFig(self,rd,daxis,taxis):
        pos = self.horizontalSlider.value()
        amplim = [self.AmpMinEdit.text(),self.AmpMaxEdit.text()]
        dispopt = [int(self.WindowSizeEdit.text()),int(self.SlidePrecEdit.text())]

        plt.ioff()
        plt.close()
        fig,ax = plt.subplots()
        subwindowsize=dispopt[0]
        slideprecision=dispopt[1]
        d_windowstep = (daxis[-1] - subwindowsize)/(slideprecision-0)      
        x_windowmin = int(round((0+pos*d_windowstep)/(daxis[1]-daxis[0])))
        x_windowmax = x_windowmin+int(round(subwindowsize/(daxis[1]-daxis[0])))
        plt.imshow(rd[:,x_windowmin:x_windowmax], cmap='gray',vmin=amplim[0], vmax=amplim[1], extent=[daxis[x_windowmin], daxis[x_windowmax], taxis[-1], taxis[0]], aspect='auto')
        ax.set_xlabel('D')
        ax.set_ylabel('T')

        fig.canvas.mpl_connect('button_press_event',self.BsInf)
        bs = FigureCanvas(fig)

        self.mainDisp.setWidget(bs)       
        return bs

    def BsInf(self,event):                          
        bs_d=event.xdata
        bs_t=event.ydata
        print(bs_d)
```

Comment: It seems like you are creating a custom figure canvas for a figure that has previously created via `pyplot`. Not sure for what purpose that is, but it might cause you some trouble. In any case you are connecting the callback to the canvas before creating it. Also, you don't keep a reference to the callback once the method returns.

Comment: I tried, and it cames to the problem that how to cite methods inside the same subclass. Inside subclass "ImDisp", I cannot cite method "BsInf" in method "BsFig". Wondering what is the reason.

Comment: Not sure what you mean by "cite method" but I suspect the problem is you don't keep a reference to the callback once the method returns, as mentionned in previous comment.

Comment: Thx. "cite method" means "call the method". I face the same problem when I add a return value (ex. return bs_d) to "BsInf".

Comment: Sorry, if that wasn't clear. Use something like `self.mycallback = fig.canvas.mpl_connect('button_press_event',self.BsInf)`

Comment: Thx. As the callback of "fig.canvas.mpl_connect" is an ID number, this doesn't matters for this problem. I narrow this problem to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54364276/how-to-cite-between-methods-inside-a-subclass

Comment: "this doesn't matters for this problem" is wrong. It sure matters if you keep a reference to a callback or not when the function returns.