# how to cite between methods inside a subclass

Tags: python, subclass, self

I would like to cite between methods inside this subclass "ImDisp", whose father class is "mywindow". But I found in "Bs" method, the 'BsInf' cannot be cited. Why?

```
class ImDisp(mywindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super(ImDisp,self).__init__()

    def BsFig(self):
        print('BsFig')

    def BsInf(self):
        print('BsInf')

    def Bs(self):
        self.BsInf #This doesn't work, why?
        print('Bs')
```

Answer (score 2):

You should call the method by adding parentheses to the function object:

```
self.BsInf()
```

Comment: Thanks. I tried "self.BsInf" to "self.BsInf()". Doesn't work.

Comment: Of course in addition you need to make sure to actually call `.BS()` at some point.

Comment: Yes. I called "ImDisp.Bs(self)" in the class "mywindow". And I can even access to any values inside "Bs". The only problem is that: I cannot access to "BsInf" through "Bs" using "self.BsInf".

Comment: Note that we have no idea what you're doing inside `mywindow`, but that may be the source of the problem. The parent also cannot know anything about the child methods unless they are present inside the parent as well. In any case you need to *instantiate*  a class to call its methods, `myinstance = ImDisp(); myinstace.BS()`